# Spring - how to display database content as a List in JSP table using service layer?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jsp

I'm trying to display a List in JSP table, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. How should I do it properly? Here is a code:

PatientDAOImpl:

```
public List<Patient> getAllpatients() throws SQLException {

    String query = "SELECT * FROM virtualclinic.patient";
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;


        con = dataSource.getConnection();
        ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        List<Patient> patients = new ArrayList<Patient>();

        Patient patient = new Patient();

        while (rs.next()) {

            patient.setId(rs.getString(1));
            patient.setName(rs.getString(2));
            patient.setLastName(rs.getString(3));
            patient.setGender(rs.getString(4));
            patient.setAge(rs.getString(5));
            patient.setPhoneNumber(rs.getString(6));
            patient.setAddress(rs.getString(7));
            patient.setDisease(rs.getString(8));
            patient.setCondition(rs.getString(9));
            patient.setRoomType(rs.getString(10));
            patient.setRoomNumber(rs.getString(11));
            patient.setDate(rs.getString(12));

            patients.add(patient);
        }

        return patients;
```

ClinicServiceImpl:

```
public List<Patient> getAllpatients() throws SQLException{
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("clinicconfig.xml");
    patientDAO = ctx.getBean("patientDAO", PatientDAOImpl.class);

    return patientDAO.getAllpatients();
}
```

InformationController:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/informations.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView infoPatient(Model model) throws SQLException{

    setAppContext();

    List<Patient> patients = clinicService.getAllpatients();

    model.addAttribute("patients", patients);

    ModelAndView inf = new ModelAndView("InformationsAboutPatient");
    return inf;

}

public void setAppContext(){
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("clinicconfig.xml");
    clinicService = ctx.getBean("clinicService", ClinicServiceImpl.class);
    }
```

Informations.jsp:

```
<table border="1">
        <tr style="font-size: 13">
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>First name</td>
            <td>Last name</td>
            <td>Gender</td>
            <td>Age</td>
            <td>Phone number</td>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td>Disease</td>
            <td>Condition</td>
            <td>Room type</td>
            <td>Room number</td>
            <td>Date registration</td>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach var="patient" items="${patients}">
            <tr style="font-size: 10">
                <td>${patient.getId()}</td>
                <td>${patient.getName()}</td>
                <td>${patient.getLastName()}</td>
                <td>${patient.getGender()}</td>
                <td>${patient.getAge()}</td>
                <td>${patient.getPhoneNumber()}</td>
                <td>${patient.getAddress()}</td>
                <td>${patient.getDisease()}</td>
                <td>${patient.getCondition()}</td>
                <td>${patient.getRoomType()}</td>
                <td>${patient.getRoomNumber()}</td>
                <td>${patient.getDate()}</td>
            </tr>
            </c:forEach>
    </table>
```

clinicconfig.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
<bean id="userDAO" class="org.damian.dao.UserDAOImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="patientDAO" class="org.damian.dao.PatientDAOImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="employeeDAO" class="org.damian.dao.EmployeeDAOImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

   <bean id="clinicService" class="org.damian.service.ClinicServiceImpl">
    <property name="userDAO" ref="userDAO" />
    <property name="patientDAO" ref="patientDAO" />
    <property name="employeeDAO" ref="employeeDAO" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

   <mvc:annotation-driven />
```

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3307/virtualclinic" />
     <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>
```

Values which are displaying in table looks same like values which I put in `<td>` form.

Comment: correct syntax to get attributes from a class isn't to call gettter but attribute name instead: `${patient.getId()}` should be `${patient.id}`

Comment: are you getting data from service? if yes... do you have any error or stacktrace?

Comment: @JordiCastilla, to the best of my knowledge (aka hackability) there's no distinction between the two; they are equivalent.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils AFAIK for methods is equivalent, but not for attributes... but maybe is just a good practice from my teacher,,, :)

Comment: @JordiCastilla, possibly although using get and set as opposed to direct access might be the "better" way :)  AFAIFound, it works like this - s.a.getB() or s.a.b or s.getA().getB() will give the same results.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils sweet to learn something new :) thanks!

Comment: @JordiCastilla no errors, no stracktrace

Comment: Can you post your jsp taglibs

Comment: @Aboodz: <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%> - its jstl 1.2, I'm not sure if you meant it

Comment: Try placing this in your JSP `<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>`

Comment: @Aboodz: it works! what exactly says this line?

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the same `Patient` Object in the loop. Instead of getting the information about different patients you'll end up getting the duplicate entries for the last patient in your `List<Patient>`.

Instead of doing this:

```
Patient patient = new Patient();
```

above the `while` loop, you should be doing it inside the `while` loop.

```
while (rs.next()) {

    /* Do Here */
    Patient patient = new Patient();

    patient.setId(rs.getString(1));
    patient.setName(rs.getString(2));
    patient.setLastName(rs.getString(3));
    patient.setGender(rs.getString(4));
    patient.setAge(rs.getString(5));
    patient.setPhoneNumber(rs.getString(6));
    patient.setAddress(rs.getString(7));
    patient.setDisease(rs.getString(8));
    patient.setCondition(rs.getString(9));
    patient.setRoomType(rs.getString(10));
    patient.setRoomNumber(rs.getString(11));
    patient.setDate(rs.getString(12));

    patients.add(patient);
}
```

Comment: @dante we're not here to guess and search for all your mistakes, you must provide some feedback with stacktraces and error messages, not say `**still doesn't work**` or at least provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This is just one of the things which you are doing incorrectly. What is `setAppContext();` doing? Could you add your XML Configuration to the question?

Comment: @JordiCastilla: I checked if service layer works well with dao and its fine, I displayed all elements in console to be sure (by system.out.prinln(patients)) and all 12 elements displayed (just like number of the patients in database)

Comment: @user2004685 I added xml file in post